# Getting undefined value in useEffect (React)

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

The below function gets the current location of a user:

```
  const getCurrentLocation = () => {
    fetch("https://ipinfo.io/json?token=$TOKEN")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((jsonResponse) => {
        console.log(jsonResponse)
        return jsonResponse;
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(getCurrentLocation());
    }, []);
```

logging in `useEffect` is showing `undefined` and it is appearing first in the console, then `jsonResponse` shows next in the console with the corresponding object. Why is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getCurrentLocation` doesn't return anything, that's why you got `undefined`.

Moreover, [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which is **asynchronous**, meaning you don't get the result immediately, you must pass a calback to `then` to get the result when it is available.

```js
const getCurrentLocation = () => {
  return fetch("https://ipinfo.io/json?token=$TOKEN")
    .then(response => response.json());
};

useEffect(() => {
  getCurrentLocation()
    .then(location => console.log(location));
}, []);
```

Comment: So that JSON which is returned, I have to use it next in another HTTP request which is after `getCurrentLocation` call. So in other words, at first I get the user location and then make another request to the server with location as a parameter. I tried to save it using useState, and add a dependency of location in useEffect, and it works, but it re-renders every time because first that state is null, then later when we get the data useEffect fires again. Could you suggest a solution for this?

Comment: I did wrap the code that make second request to server inside this `then`: `getCurrentLocation()
    .then(location => console.log(location));
` and pass location as a parameter. But this seems a bit messy, I thought maybe there is some more elegant way of doing it ?

Comment: you can write `getCurrentLocation().then(location => getAnotherThing(location).then(res => console.log(res))`

Answer (score 0):

The `getCurrentLocation` function is not returning anything. Try saving the location in the state, so that you can access it when needed:

```
const [currentLocation, setCurrentLocation] = useState(null);

const getCurrentLocation = () => {
  fetch("https://ipinfo.io/json?token=$TOKEN")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((jsonResponse) => {
      setCurrentLocation(jsonResponse); // <- save the location in state
    });
};

useEffect(() => {
  getCurrentLocation();
}, []);

return <div>{currentLocation}</div>
```

If you need the location in a `useEffect`, you could do:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (currentLocation !== null) {
    // ...
  }
}, [currentLocation])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use async/await to get response, take a look at this one:

```
 const getCurrentLocation = async () => {
    const result = await fetch("https://ipinfo.io/json?token=$TOKEN");
    return result.json();
  };



 const handleGetLocation = async () => {
   const result = await getCurrentLocation();
   console.log(result);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleGetLocation();
  }, []);
```